# dojo using custom module from custom cdn source

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

we can use dojo toolkit after reference dojo script in our html page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/dom"], function (dom) {
        var button = dom.getById("ok");
    });
</script>
```

we can use **"dojo/dom"** in our script.

I want to create my own javascript module in my server and use it everyvhere.

For example I have a domain http://mydomain.com/api/v1/app.js

I should use this **app.js** like this.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script src="//mydomain.com/api/v1/app.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/dom","app/something"], function (dom,something) {

    var st = new something();
    });
</script>
```

I created **app.js** file like this but did not work.

```
declare(["dojo/_base/declare"],
    function (declare) {
        return declare(null, {
            constructor: function () {
                console.log("hello");
            }
        });
})
```

How should I create my app.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues here. The first one (and the real issue) is that Dojo will look relatively for your modules. This means that it will look somewhere on the CDN for your app module (which it obviously can't find).

To change the location of a package you have to configure the package section of the [Dojo config](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojo_config/). In your case that would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojoConfig = {
        packages: [{
            name: 'custom',
            location: 'http://mydomain.com/api/v1/'
        }]
    }
</script>
```

Then you can get your module using:

```
require(["custom/app"], function(app) {
    // Do something
});
```

**Important**: Make sure that the Dojo config is loaded before the Dojo loader (`dojo.js`). So you have to put this `<script>`-tag above the `dojo.js` script tag to make it work.

---

Another issue is that in `app.js` you have to use `define()` as the first statement and **not** `declare()`. For example:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"],
    function (declare) {
        return declare(null, {
            constructor: function () {
                console.log("hello");
            }
        });
})
```

Comment: This is great solution. I wonder something else. Can I create multiple modules in same app.js. For example require(["custom/app","custom/app2","custom/app2"]...

Comment: Question2: we are not edit dojoConfig for packages to use dojo toolkit. but we are edited dojoConfig for our custom api.

Comment: If you create a file called `app2.js` then you can use `custom/app2`.